# How many numbers need to be selected to guarantee that at least one pair of these numbers add up to 80?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose someone is randomly selecting numbers from the set:

$\{2x-1\ |\ 1\leq x \leq 40\} = \{1, 3, 5,...,75,77,79\}$

without repetition. How many numbers need to be selected to guarantee that at least one pair of these numbers add up to $80$?

The answer came to be $21$. How is this so?

Please provide clear explanation, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Pigeonhole principle.  You have the partition $\{1,79\},\{3,77\},\{5,75\},\dots,\{39,41\}$.  How many sets?  If you have two elements from the same set what do you notice?  What does pigeonhole principle have to say about how many numbers you need to guarantee at least two come from the same set?

Comment: "If k+1 objects are assigned to k places, then at
least one place must be assigned at least two
objects" That's what my professor has under her slide.

Comment: And with "twenty places" being the twenty sets: $\{1,79\},\{3,77\},\dots$ and using twenty one numbers...

Comment: So there are twenty sets, where two elements can add up to 80? in each set..up to 20.

Answer (score 1):

Group the set into pairs as such: $$\left\{\{1,79\},\{3,77\},\cdots,\{39,41\}\right\}$$

Observe that the pairs all add up to $80$, and there is no other way to add up to $80$.

Therefore, we need to choose randomly such that both numbers of any pair is chosen.

The worst case scenario would be that no pairs have both numbers chosen.

We have $20$ pairs, so the worst case scenario would be that only one number of those $20$ pairs are chosen: $$\{1,3,\cdots,39\}$$

Therefore, we would need to choose $21$ times to guarantee that.

Comment: Sorry for a silly question, but how did you get 20 pairs?

Comment: I used my hands and feet to count.

Comment: There are $40$ elements in the original set because the original set is a mapping of $\{1,2,\cdots,40\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $S = \{2k - 1 \mid k \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \leq k \leq 40\} = \{1, 3, 5, \ldots, 79\}$ consists of the $40$ positive odd numbers less than $80$. A pair of odd numbers that has sum $80$ has the form $\{m, 80 - m\}$.  The set $S$ contains $20$ such pairs:
$$\{1, 79\}, \{3, 77\}, \{5, 75\}, \ldots, \{39, 41\}$$
To guarantee that we obtain a pair with sum $80$, we must select both numbers from one of these two-element subsets.  The worst case scenario is that as we keep making selections, we choose exactly one number from each of these twenty subsets, so selecting only $20$ numbers from set $S$ does not guarantee that we will obtain a pair that has sum $80$.  On the other hand, if we select $21$ numbers from set $S$, by the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), we must select both numbers from at least one of these $20$ two-element subsets. Consequently, if we select $21$ numbers from set $S$, we will select at least one pair with sum $80$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is based on pegionhole principle.We have to contradict the statement and as maximum we can contradict we get the answer.So let's contradict:-
From the given numbers $80=1+79=3+77=5+75$ & so on......As there are 80 odd numbers ,so the total numbers we have are $40$ out of which $20$ pairs can be made which add upto $80$.

Now the contradiction begins :- pick all the numbers which can not add upto $80$ in pair of two.Pick the beginning $20$ numbers because we have seen that without their pair from the backend they are not making $80$.Now we have got the maximum negativity($20$) because if we take one more number i.e. $41$ we have $39$ for that.So we have to take $21$ numbers to be sure.

If we think of it another way ,let's take any of the $20$ numbers that don't add upto $80$ in pair of two ,the second number doesn't have its pair, the third one also don't have & so on upto $20^{th}$ ,so logically if $(A,B)$ is the pair then we have taken either $ A $ or $B$ of each of the $20$ pairs, thus the next number we select would be the counterpart of any one of the $20$ already selected numbers(if that was $A$ then it would be $B$ or vice versa),because there is no $21^{th}$ pair ,so we have to take $21$ numbers to be sure.